# Running multiple mqtt servers with different ports on windows

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, mqtt

I implemented two MQTT servers on asp.net core 2.0 C#, and want to run both of them on the windows server. This is my code in startup (another one is on port 1884):

```
var mqttServerOptions = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
  .WithDefaultEndpointPort(1885)
  .Build();
services
  .AddHostedMqttServer(mqttServerOptions)
  .AddMqttConnectionHandler()
  .AddConnections()
  .AddMqttTcpServerAdapter();
```

I tried to used different ports to handle it, but only one of them is working at the same time(the other one does not get requests). (I opened the ports on windows firewall)
How can I handle that?

Comment: Parametrize the port and execute two instance of the ASP.NET Core program.

Comment: I put different port on each one and ran each one as a separate website with dedicated application pool. But it does not work. Only one of them is working.